# Mount USB Storage recognised by "usb-devices" but not by "lsblk"

Tags: debian, mount, usb, removable-storage

I have Debian Wheezy based router, kernel version `3.10.107` After plugging in USB storage, it is not recognized by `lsblk`. However, it looks like it is detected by the OS since the command `usb-devices` is listing it.

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=054c ProdID=09c2 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Sony
S:  Product=Storage Media
S:  SerialNumber=5C0710488A173BC108
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=498mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

lsblk output:

```
root@ubnt:/# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop8          7:8    0  80.1M  1 loop
mmcblk0rpmb  179:24   0   512K  0 disk
mmcblk0boot0 179:8    0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk0boot1 179:16   0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk0      179:0    0   3.7G  0 disk
|-mmcblk0p1  179:1    0   142M  0 part
`-mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   3.4G  0 part
mtdblock0     31:0    0     1M  1 disk
mtdblock1     31:1    0     3M  1 disk
mtdblock2     31:2    0    64K  1 disk
```

dmesg output:

```
usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi1 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Sony     Storage Media    PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
```

Tried with ext3 formatted device, still not recognized.

Is there any way to mount it and use it as a normal USB storage?

Comment: Please edit question with output in `dmesg` after you plug in the USB storage device. Is the USB storage device formatted? With a FAT filesystem? Is the Linux on your router configured with FAT support?

Comment: Also, since all the other disks seem to be MMC and MTD devices, the `sd_mod` module might not be loaded. It is responsible for all SCSI-disk-like storage devices, including among other things SAS, SATA, USB and libata-supported PATA devices - but as far as I know, it is not needed for `mmcblk` and `mtdblock` devices.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, looks like this is the case (missing sd_mod driver). I will update this question soon and try to add the missing driver.

Comment: @telcoM Awesome! Works. Luckily the scsi sd_mod.ko driver was found on the device itself so I did not needed to compile it on my own, and I am not sure why its not loaded. After I loaded the module, the USB appeared in the block devices list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily the scsi sd_mod.ko driver was found on the device itself so I did not needed to compile it on my own. After I loaded the module,

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.107-UBNT/kernel/drivers/scsi/sd_mod.ko
```

the USB appeared in the block devices list.

```
root@ubnt:/home/ubnt# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    1  28.9G  0 disk
`-sda1         8:1    1  28.9G  0 part
loop8          7:8    0  80.1M  1 loop
mmcblk0rpmb  179:24   0   512K  0 disk
mmcblk0boot0 179:8    0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk0boot1 179:16   0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk0      179:0    0   3.7G  0 disk
|-mmcblk0p1  179:1    0   142M  0 part
`-mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   3.4G  0 part
mtdblock0     31:0    0     1M  1 disk
mtdblock1     31:1    0     3M  1 disk
mtdblock2     31:2    0    64K  1 disk
root@ubnt:/home/ubnt#
```